# Support for fraction of a cent pricing

Tags: pricing

We have simple products that are sold in large quantities that we price to a fraction of a sent (e.g. `$4.125`) Users buy 8 and their cost is `$33`.

We don't see support for this in Magento or any extension. If make the change to allow admins to enter prices like `4.125` what is the sense of how many things are going to break?

Are we going to have to touch every report that involves money? Imports and exports?

Admin and consumer checkout? The dashboard?

Anyone want to offer an opinion on the effort we're looking at to do this?

Comment: There's been a good discussion about this in:re to Magento 2 and what should be supported. See: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/636

Answer (score 0):

Let's say ıt should be 1 dollar and 50 cents.

You can show that in magento like 1.50 or to be precise you can show it 1,50.

```
lib/Zend/Locale/Data/id.xml
 <currencyFormats>
 <currencyFormatLength>
 <currencyFormat>
 <pattern>¤#.##0,00</pattern> 
 </currencyFormat>
 </currencyFormatLength>
 </currencyFormats>


 <currencyFormats>
 <currencyFormatLength>
 <currencyFormat>
 <pattern>¤#,##0.00</pattern>
 </currencyFormat>
 </currencyFormatLength>
 </currencyFormats>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently (and am still working on) a project that requires pricing down to 5 digits of precision. Since I did not feel comfortable with changing price database fields from `DEC(12,4)` to, say, `DEC(12,6)`, I decided instead to create my own entities that are assigned to products. These entities basically give me a way to save the price (ie. 0.32012) in a text field which I can then use to calculate the price with an observer as necessary. The same technique could be used for a basic product attribute (text type).

The database will indeed save a value such as 4.125, the problem is that this value gets rounded to only two decimal places in several different places. There is a module that claims to fix this so that you are able to save 4.125, but it might have limitations that you don't like. I'd give it a look at least: https://github.com/aurmil/magento-set-price-precision